# How to use nsupdate to update a wildcard dns record

Tags: domain-name-system, dynamic-ip, nsupdate

So for our dev environment we have a wildcard A record for each of our developers. Having different needs (vpn vs office, etc) we allow update on the dns via nsupdate. That works pretty well but I haven't found a way to update a wildcard entry via nsupdate. Did I miss something obvious ?

I try "update add *.domain.com 600 A 10.2.2.2" but that is refused while if I used  x213.domain.com it's working properly.

Is there some magic syntax? Or this is simply not possible...

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question? I'm running into the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Better late than never? I'll just add my answer here since I found your question when looking for an answer myself.

Just "slashing" the asterisk worked out fine for me.

```
update add \*.domain.com 600 A 10.2.2.2
```

Comment: I don't have this environment anymore to confirm... If someone else can vote/confirm this I'll gladly accept it ^^

Comment: I can confirm...